# Java Applet "notloaded"

Tags: java, html, netbeans, applet, loading

I am having trouble embedding a super simple applet into my website. When I open the page, the console on the bottom bar says "Applet TestApplet notloaded" and the text "Error. Click for details" in the space where the applet should run. I used filezilla to push the html and .class file to "http://nuevawave.org/sandbox/JavaGallery/". The html file is called Test.html . The applet works fine when I run it from netbeans.

Here is the html:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test Page</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      words...
      <applet codebase ="http://nuevawave.org/sandbox/JavaGallery/" code="TestApplet.class"  width="250" height="300" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I click the dialogue it opens a dialogue which says "Application failed to run. There was an error while executing the application. Click for more details." Clicking the details button opens the java console, but no errors are present. I put xxxxxxx instead of the real URL.

Comment: There you go. The webpage is nuevawave.org/sandbox/JavaGallery/Test.html

Answer (score 0):

> ..Clicking the details button opens the java console, but no errors are present.

My version of FF is more informative.

```
...
Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TestApplet 
    (wrong name: test/TestApplet)
```

This indicates the applet is in the package `test`, and should therefore be located at..

http://nuevawave.org/sandbox/JavaGallery/test/TestApplet.class

At the moment it is here..

http://nuevawave.org/sandbox/JavaGallery/TestApplet.class

---

### Edit 1

After more snooping around that site, I threw the following together.

#### HTML

Put this HTML at http://nuevawave.org/sandbox/JavaGallery/applet.html

```
<html>
<body>
<applet
    codebase="."
    archive="TestApplet.jar"
    code="test.TestApplet2"
    width="250"
    height="300">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Output

> I freaking love computers!

Comment: Thanks. I don't have access to the server right now, but I'll let you know once I get back.

Comment: I got back and put TestApplet.class into a folder called "test". It still didn't work :( I even tried putting the html in there too with no luck.